# How to sort products in django?

Tags: django

There is a page with products. Can you tell me how to make sure that the goods are sorted in the way that the user chose in the form?That is, there was a button that the user clicked on and could sort the goods, for example, from the cheapest to the most expensive, and vice versa, then he could sort the goods by novelty, etc

Water code:

models.py

```py
class Product (models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50,verbose_name='Заголовок')
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=255,unique=True,db_index=True,verbose_name='URL')
    content = models.TextField(blank=True,verbose_name='Общее описание')
    structure = models.TextField(blank=True,verbose_name='Состав')
    care = models.TextField(blank=True,verbose_name='Уход')
    photo = models.ImageField(upload_to="photo/%Y/%m/%d/",blank=True,verbose_name='Фото')
    photo2 = models.ImageField(upload_to="photo/%Y/%m/%d/",blank=True, verbose_name='Фото2')
    photo3 = models.ImageField(upload_to="photo/%Y/%m/%d/",blank=True, verbose_name='Фото3')
    time_create = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True,verbose_name='Время создания')
    time_update = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True,verbose_name='Время изменения')
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=15,decimal_places=2,verbose_name='Цена')
    available = models.BooleanField(default=True,verbose_name='Наличие')
    is_published = models.BooleanField(default=True,verbose_name='Публикация')
    prod_sub_category = models.ForeignKey('Category', on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING,verbose_name='Выберите категорию')
    subproduct = models.ForeignKey('Subcategory', on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING,verbose_name='Выберите подкатегорию')
```

Comment: Do you have code which shows the products in the wrong order? What have you tried? Where did you get stuck?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You have to specify sorting using query sets.If you can provide other parts(views) of the code, it will be easy to analyse.